# Convert to Hrs:min from decimal vlaue jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, datetime, decimal

I have a decimal value like 75.75. Then I want to convert this in to Hours:Minute as 76:15 (as .75 means 60 + 15 -> 1 hour and 15 mins). So how can we achieve this using jquery..
example: 10.40 then 10.40
         10.80 then 11.20

Can anyone help me to do this..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: **decimal** value like 75.75 ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use below JavaScript code to get the output in desired format

```js
function calctime() {
  var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var sep = x.indexOf(".");
  var hh = Number(x.substr(0, sep));
  var mm = Number(x.substr(sep + 1, x.length - sep - 1));
  var mm1 = Number(mm / 60);
  var mm = mm % 60;
  hh = hh + mm1;
  alert(Math.floor(hh) + ":" + mm);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<button title="Calculate" onclick="calctime()">Calculate</button>
```